# Flutter Form Builder issue. The getter 'fields' isn't defined for the type 'FormState'

Tags: flutter, forms, validation, flutter-form-builder

I'm following the example [here](https://github.com/flutter-form-builder-ecosystem/flutter_form_builder/blob/c964ef103784f5aea10975d54eafd58dae817a1f/example/lib/main.dart#L186) to build a form

```
                FormBuilderTextField(
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                  name: 'age',
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Age',
                    suffixIcon: _ageHasError
                        ? const Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.red)
                        : const Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.green),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _ageHasError = !(_formKey.currentState?.fields['age']
                              ?.validate() ??
                          false);
                    });
                  },
                  // valueTransformer: (text) => num.tryParse(text),
                  validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
                    FormBuilderValidators.required(),
                    FormBuilderValidators.numeric(),
                    FormBuilderValidators.max(70),
                  ]),
                  // initialValue: '12',
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                )
```

I get an error at Line 186

```
 _ageHasError = !(_formKey.currentState?.fields['age']
```

Here's the error

```
The getter 'fields' isn't defined for the type 'FormState'.
```

I'm following the example as is. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: are you trying to get age value from  FormBuilderTextField

Comment: @YeasinSheikh While following the example (github link in the post), I get this error. I see that when the button is pressed, the _ageHasError value is calculated to either whether the input box has passed validation or not. But the example as is (without any changes) throws this error and I don't see the 'fields' attribute in _formKey.currentState.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the latest version of the package, and don't forget to add key. I am using `flutter_form_builder: ^7.7.0` and run this widget.

```dart
class FTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const FTest({super.key});

  @override
  State<FTest> createState() => _FTestState();
}

class _FTestState extends State<FTest> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FormBuilder(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            FormBuilderTextField(
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
              name: 'age',
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Age',
              ),
              onChanged: (val) {
                print(_formKey.currentState?.fields["age"]?.value);
              },
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```